# @SpringBootTest Toggable webEnvironment?

Tags: java, spring-boot-test, spring-profiles

I want to toggle the webEnvironment config inside SpringBootTest to support running the tests in a pipeline (where the tests needs to be able to boot the server themselves) and locally (where I want to use a standalone server for faster tests.

Figured having a Profile which I could set would be a good solution to it but SpringBootTest seems to flat out ignore whatever profile I attach at the same level, is it simply too early in Spring's lifecycle for it to pick up profiles? Is there a better way to do this?

```
@Profile("myProfile")
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.DEFINED_PORT) // Starts regardless of what @Profile is
public class MyClass{
   ...
}
```

E: Related question:
[SpringBootTest enable/disable webEnvironment based on input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51539714/springboottest-enable-disable-webenvironment-based-on-input)

E2: After some discussion down below I'm ditching the remote mode, not worth the hassle.

Comment: JUnit creates tests, not Spring. JUnit doesn’t care about Spring annotations.

Comment: Try \@ActiveProfiles annotation instead.

Comment: @ActiveProfiles only activates a profile though? If I do that I still don't get the wanted behavior of being able to toggle if the application should start or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was wondering why do you even need to rely on spring here? JUnit already has `@EnabledIf` annotation ([documentation](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/5.7.1/api/org.junit.jupiter.api/org/junit/jupiter/api/condition/EnabledIf.html)), so you can use it to not even attempt to run the test.

In my understanding it's even better, because this will work for all the tests that might even not run spring (unit tests for example). Also it should be better from the performance endpoint (you don't try to even run the Application Context, find/register beans, etc.)

Comment: Sorry if it was unclear, modified OP to try to clarify. I want to run the test regardless of what SpringBootTest is but one config should boot up the server on its own and the other one expects it to be running already, somewhere.


As it's the same set of tests regardless I do not want to duplicate all tests and have two sets of SpringBootTest.

Comment: To add - all tests in this module are integration tests so no need to worry about unit tests.

Comment: Can you clarify what do you mean by "running somewhere, already"? SpringBootTest is meant to run the server by itself... otherwise, you could use @ContextConfiguration / or maybe SpringBootTest with a parameter that will denote the configuration to load the beans from, but again, please supply more information of what you're trying to achieve

Comment: Sure, locally I start the application in WSL with 'mvn spring-boot:run' and then just the run integration tests from inside IntelliJ. However this will create issues in buildpipes as I need to add steps to maven for it to boot the server in a similar fashion which seems like a giant headache to get working properly, so for that reason I want the SpringBootTest annotation to be toggleable.

Comment: If you use @SpringBootTest annotation you shouldn't really run a remote application, why not just support `@SpringBootTest` annotated tests, I mean why do you want to run a remote application when you run the tests locally?

Comment: My reason was that running it embedded locally makes application messages and integration messages spit out to the same console but thinking about it again it really isn't all that much of an issue.